# Log4j2 not generating file using log4j-core 2.16.0

Tags: spring-boot, properties, log4j2

I have updated my log4j version to log4j-core 2.16. I have added one more dependency as per the document. And I am using log4j2.properties for the appender and file generation process. But my file is not generating in the given location.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You'll need to provide more details, such as the contents of your `log4j2.properties` file, the file containing your dependencies (are you using Maven or Gradle?) -- both before and after your update.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.